# Passwordless user for Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) using Cloud SQL Proxy?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The documentation [About the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) contains a line, “[B]ecause the proxy always connects from a hostname that cannot be accessed except by the proxy, you can create a user account that can be used only by the proxy. The advantage of doing this is that you can specify this account without a password without compromising the security of your instance or your data.”

Is there any practical way of connecting a MySQL client through the Google Cloud Proxy which is authenticated using a Service Account that is only allowed to access a specific MySQL user?

One potential way to restrict access when using the Cloud SQL Proxy is to [create a MySQL user account with Cloud SQL Proxy IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#user): `'[USER_NAME]'@'cloudsqlproxy~[IP_ADDRESS]'`. But this would not work for a service account that runs on multiple cloud VMs. This is basically authentication of the MySQL user by IP address instead of by Service Account.

A second way to restrict a Service Account to a MySQL user might be to use a MySQL user account `'[USER_NAME]'@'cloudsqlproxy~%'` and rely on IAM to restrict access. The Service Account running the Cloud SQL Client [requires](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#service-account) the `roles/cloudsql.client` role, which is equivalent to the `cloudsql.instances.connect` and `cloudsql.instances.get` permissions. Unfortunately, if you grant multiple Service Accounts this role, then it looks like there is no way to restrict them from using each other’s MySQL user.

A third potential way to enable passwordless authentication might be to use client certificates ([`gcloud sql ssl-certs create [CERT_NAME] client-key.pem --instance [INSTANCE_NAME]`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance#managing_your_client_certificates)). But client private keys are even harder to manage than passwords, since they are all invalidated at the same time in under 1 year when you refresh the server certificate: “When you refresh your server cerficate, you must also generate new client certificates; the existing client certificates are revoked.” This makes them basically impossible to use in production.

Basically, it seems like the Cloud SQL Proxy does not enable authenticating to a specific MySQL user via an IAM Service Account. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s ironic that the so-called “Auth proxy” hasn’t provided database user authentication until now. Google Cloud SQL has finally added support for passwordless IAM login, where [`cloud-sql-proxy`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy) (or the [golang](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector), [java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory), or [python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) connector) authenticates the IAM user or service account and then connects to the [Auth proxy server in front of MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) with an ephemeral client certificate.

For Postgres, Cloud SQL added [manual IAM Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#logging-in-as-a-user) in 2020 ([Cloud SQL Release Notes: 2020-10-12](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#October_12_2020)), and they added [automatic IAM Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#logging_in_with_automatic) and cloud-sql-proxy support in 2021 [`-enable_iam_login`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/tree/v1.33.1#-enable_iam_login)([cloud-sql-proxy changelog: 1.20.0 2021-02-24](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1200-2021-02-24), [Cloud SQL Release Notes: 2021-04-06](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#April_06_2021), generally available on [2021-08-30](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#August_30_2021)), though that flag is replaced with `--auto-iam-authn` in 2.0.0.

For MySQL, Cloud SQL added [manual IAM Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authentication#manual) in 2021 ([Cloud SQL Release Notes: 2021-07-08](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#July_08_2021)). Automatic IAM Authentication is not documented yet, but it was unlocked in [golang cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn 1.1.0](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#110-2022-12-06) and cloud[-sql-proxy 2.0.0-preview.4 (2022-12-12)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#200-preview4-2022-12-12) with `--auto-iam-authn`.

Passwordless IAM authentication on Google Cloud SQL MySQL requires:

- `roles/cloudsql.instanceUser` role, or equivalently `cloudsql.instances.get`  and `cloudsql.instances.login` permissions ([MySQL IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/iam-roles#roles))
- `--cloudsql_iam_authentication=on` on the MySQL server ([Instance configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authentication#instance_configuration_for))
- User created with `type` set for IAM authentication: `gloud sql users create --type=cloud_iam_user --instance=MY_INSTANCE USERNAME@DOMAIN`, or `gloud sql users create --type=cloud_iam_service_account --instance=MY_INSTANCE SERVICE@PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
- Either manual or automatic IAM authentication

  - Manual IAM authentication: requires the username to be the local-part of the email address, the password to be set to the result of `gcloud sql generate-login-token`, `--enable-cleartext-plugin`, and requires connecting using a certificate generated by `gcloud sql ssl client-certs create` ([Log in with manual IAM database authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/iam-logins#logging-in-as-a-user))
  - Automatic IAM authentication: requires generating an ephemeral client certificate [generateEphemeralCert](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/connect/generateEphemeralCert) with access_token set to the result of `gcloud auth print-access-token`, and requires connecting with the Cloud SQL Proxy protocol (port 3307) (it does **not** work as a client certificate on port 3306). This is all automated by cloud-sql-proxy or one of the language connectors. Then you connect to cloud-sql-proxy with the username set to the local-part of the email address, and the password is ignored. Example:

  ```bash
  # Download v2.0.0-preview.4 or higher
  wget https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy/v2.0.0-preview.4/cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64
  chmod +x cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64
  sudo mv cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64 /usr/local/bin/cloud-sql-proxy

  cloud-sql-proxy --port=3306 --auto-iam-authn $(gcloud sql instances describe MY_INSTANCE --format='value(connectionName)') &
  mysql --user=MY_USERNAME --password= --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --ssl-mode=disabled
  ```

Comment: I appreciate your comments as someone else rummaging around in the dark.
Do IIUC that if you are using generateEphemeralCert, that you do not need to run the cloud-sql-proxy, and in essence, you have moved that logic in-process?

I was attempting to use the ephemeral cert to connect directly, which it rejected with unrecognized CA, but your comment about the port change made me realize I missed switching to 3307 - but still just get closed connections ("server closed the connection unexpectedly").

My next step is to try using the Python connector rather than my C++ re-implementation.

Comment: Using the cloud-sql-proxy Docker image (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-kubernetes#deploy_the_sample_app) and without providing any password in the Docker files, but just connecting to the local port: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-auth-proxy#connect-to-proxy worked for me. Still a bit more involved then just having a C++ library, but it works.